# Adding query parameter to the GET url in iOS in Swift3

Tags: ios, swift3, get, xcode8

I have an URL with

https://api.asiancar.com/api/applicationsettings

It is basically a GET url so I need to pass a `boolean` "isMobile" and `timestamp` as query parameters . How to achieve this as the ultimate URL after passing the query will look like this:

https://api.asiancar.com/api/applicationsettings?timestamp=111122244556789879&isMobile=true

```
let queryItems = [
    NSURLQueryItem(timestamp: "1234568878788998989", isMobile: true),
    NSURLQueryItem(timestamp: "1234568878788998989", isMobile: true)
]
let urlComps = NSURLComponents(string: "www.api.asiancar.com/api/applicationsettings")!
urlComps.queryItems = queryItems
let URL = urlComps.URL!
```

Am I doing right or any other modification ? please tell.

Comment: you can create String of url first and then use `let URL = URL(string: "")` to create final URL.

Comment: please post the answer

Comment: even though the accepted answer will technically work, I strongly recommend you review my answer and continue to work with url components. They are more flexible and less prone to error once you become accustomed to them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try an alternative way by using String

```
let baseUrlString = "https://api.asiancar.com/api/"
let timeStamp = 1234568878788998989
let isMobile = true
let settingsUrlString = "\(baseUrlString)applicationsettings?timestamp=\(timeStamp)&isMobile=\(isMobile)"
print(settingsUrlString)
let url = URL(string: settingsUrlString)
```

output : https://api.asiancar.com/api/applicationsettings?timestamp=1234568878788998989&isMobile=true

Answer (score 3):

Unless you have subclassed `NSURLQueryItem`, then your init method is not correct. Per [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlqueryitem) for `NSURLQueryItem`, the init method signature is:

```
init(name: String, value: String?)
```

This means your query items should be created like this:

```
let queryItems = [NSURLQueryItem(name: "timestamp" value: "1234568878788998989"), NSURLQueryItem(name: "isMobile", value: "true")]
```

This will properly add them to the url in the format you are expecting.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
let API_PREFIX = "www.api.asiancar.com/api/applicationsettings"

 var url : URL? = URL.init(string: API_PREFIX + queryItems(dictionary: [name: "isMobile", value: "true"] as [String : Any]))

func queryItems(dictionary: [String:Any]) -> String {
        var components = URLComponents()
        print(components.url!)
        components.queryItems = dictionary.map {
            URLQueryItem(name: $0, value: $1  as String)
        }
       return (components.url?.absoluteString)!
    }
```